# Excel 2007 How To Reference A Seperate Cell In WS1 From A Common Cell In WS2

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a simple file with two worksheets in. In the first worksheet (a product list) are a number of columns, including `Product Code` and `Product Description`. In the second worksheet (dispatches in January), I have `Product Code`. I need to insert a new column with the associated `Product Description` field completed based on the relevant line from the first worksheet.

I'm sure this is very easy, but its not something I've done before.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx)

In the second column of sheet 2 you would use something like `=vlookup(A1,sheet1!$A$1:$B$100,2,false)` where `A1` is your product code, `sheet1!$A$1:$B:100` is the table of product codes and descriptions, `2` is the column that contains product descriptions and `false` is for perfect matches only.

You can then drag this down and it will look up the product codes for you and return the descriptions